# Why am I missing silent post transactions?

Tags: authorize.net, silent-post, authorize.net-arb

I'm new to Authorize.net. We're setting up recurring transactions with ARB and we have our Silent Post page set up.

Yesterday we put in 4 transactions, and Silent Post only turned up 3. The day before, we put in 2 and only got back 1. I'm not sure if this is coincidence, or if it means something that we're getting back 1 less transaction than we put in. In both cases, it was the final transaction that didn't go through. (We did, however, get the confirmation email for all of them, so we can safely assume that they sent the transaction out).

Our silent post page is set up simply. It just takes what's given and sends it to a function which puts the data into a database. It also is dumping it into a log file.

Are there any common reasons why something like this would happen?

Answer (score 1):

That's actually very odd. Silent Post is triggered for every transaction sent through Authorize.Net regardless of the means (AIM, ARB, CIM, SIM, virtual terminal) or result (approved, declined, error, split tender). Each one is independent of the others so one cannot be affecting another.

Is there anything common between the two missing transactions besides being the last ones of the day? Like are both declined transactions? Or maybe have the same fields blank? That's what I would look at first in trying to troubleshoot this.

Comment: We could not discern any differences. Tonight all of our test transactions went through. We did change AVS settings, however. We loosened the restrictions. Perhaps that was the culprit?

Comment: With an issue as strange as this is it certainly a possibility. Glad you got it figured out.